# Drive letter removed from path when retrieiving sub directories

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, subdirectory

I am trying to retrieve the subdirectories of a directory in delphi, I am using this function:

```
procedure GetSubDirectories(const directory : string; list : TStrings) ;
 var
   sr : TSearchRec;
 begin
   try
     if FindFirst(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + '*.*', faDirectory, sr) < 0 then
       Exit
     else
     repeat
       if ((sr.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) AND (sr.Name <> '.') AND (sr.Name <> '..')) then
         List.Add(IncludeTrailingPathDelimiter(directory) + sr.Name) ;
     until FindNext(sr) <> 0;
   finally
     SysUtils.FindClose(sr) ;
   end;
 end;
```

Then I tried something like:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  var
    folders: TStringList;
  begin
    folders := TStringList.Create;
    try
      GetSubDirectories('c:\', folders);
      ShowMessage(folders.ValueFromIndex[0]);
    finally
      FreeAndNil(folders);
   end;
  end;
```

And the string shown in the messagebox is for example: ":\Program Files". I tried adding a breakpoitn on the `List.Add` in GetSubDirectories procedure and then the var looks like "C:\Program Files".

**Why is the drive letter being removed in the message box?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ValueFromIndex` requires you to use key-value pairs on `TStringList` what you're looking for is probably the `Strings` property of `TStringList` which is also the default propery of the class.

So you could use `folders[0]` or `folders.Strings[0]`

Comment: Thank you, it was that simple.

Comment: This might be a good link to get you started http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/RTL.asp?Name=TStringList